# Problem on Nodejs > MySQL Database communication

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

My website sends this requisition to NodeJS, which i need to return me the data (even if empty) without any type of crash/error.

```
function carregarsolicitacoes(){
fetch('/carregar-solicitacoes?usertag=' + localStorage.getItem('usertag'))
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  var select = document.getElementById('solic');
  data.forEach(solicitacao => {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = solicitacao;
    select.add(option);
  });
  getarqproj();
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Erro ao carregar as solicitações:', error);
});
}
```

which then communicates with my MySQL Database via this

```
app.get('/carregar-solicitacoes', async function(req, res) {
  var solicitacoes = [];
  const usertag = req.query.usertag;

  try {
    const conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const result = await conn.query("SELECT projtag FROM notificacoes WHERE usertag = ?", [usertag]);
    
    const results = await Promise.all(result.map(row => {
      return conn.query("SELECT projetos.nome FROM projetos WHERE projtag = ?", [row.projtag]);
    }));

    results.forEach(result => {
      if (result.length > 0) {
        var linhasolicitacao = "Convite para o projeto " + result[0].nome;
        solicitacoes.push(linhasolicitacao);
      }
    });

    res.send(solicitacoes);
    conn.release();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send('Erro ao buscar as solicitações no banco de dados.');
  }
});
```

but i'm getting this error and i can't solve it

```
/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/pool.js:49
return process.nextTick(() => cb(null, connection));
^
TypeError: cb is not a function
at /app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/pool.js:49:37
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

for reference, this is a requisition that's working perfectly:

```
function logar() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/fazer-login');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById('quadrado').classList.add('sucesso');
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('quadrado').classList.remove('sucesso');
          localStorage.setItem('islogged', 1);
          localStorage.setItem('usuario', document.getElementById('usu').value);
          localStorage.setItem('usertag', '');
          localStorage.setItem('nomeproj', '');
          localStorage.setItem('descproj', '');
          localStorage.setItem('projtag', '');
          localStorage.setItem('iscriador', '');
          location.replace("/index3.html");
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('quadrado').classList.add('falha');
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById('quadrado').classList.remove('falha');
          window.alert('Erro ao logar, verifique as informações inseridas.');
        }, 1000);
      }
    };
    const dados = 'usu=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('usu').value) +
      '&sen=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('sen').value);
    xhr.send(dados);
  }
```

```
app.post('/fazer-login', function (req, res) {
  const usu = req.body.usu;
  const sen = req.body.sen;

  pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro ao se conectar ao banco de dados:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Erro ao se conectar ao banco de dados.');
      return;
    }

    conn.query('SELECT * FROM contas WHERE nick = ? AND senha = ?', [usu, sen], (err, result) => {
      conn.release();

      if (err) {
        console.error('Erro ao realizar a consulta ao banco de dados:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Erro ao realizar a consulta ao banco de dados.');
        return;
      }

      if (result.length > 0) {
        usertag = result[0].nicktag;
        islogged = 1;
        usuario = usu;
        res.redirect('index3.html');
      } else {
        res.status(401).send('Usuário ou senha inválidos');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Please help!

i expect the data to return without any type of error or crash

Comment: Note that the "working" `app,post` does not appear to build a `conn`, it already exists. So: why does `app.get` create a new one? Also, that error does not look like it's the full error, can you update it to include the entire stack trace?

Comment: Don't do multiple queries. Do a single query that joins the `notificacoes` and `projetos` tables.

Comment: `SELECT p.nome FROM notificacoes AS n JOIN projetos AS p USING (projtag) WHERE n.usertag = ?`

Comment: Comment from Mike helped me solve it, and thanks for the other suggestions, i'm new to NodeJS + MySQL so the code is far from perfect.